# Name of and references for the equivalence relation $x \sim y :\Longleftrightarrow x^2 = y^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, terminology, equivalence-relations

Playing around with the concepts of *negativity* and *positivity*, I came across the following equivalence relation defined for all elements $x,y$ of a field $\mathbb{F}$:
$$
x \sim y :\Longleftrightarrow x^2 = y^2.
$$

I would like to read more about it; but without a name, I cannot find appropriate references. A superficial search resulted in the concept of [square classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_class). However, this is not really what I was looking for.

Besides, when $\mathbb{F} := \mathbb{R}$, is it correct that the set of non-negative real numbers, $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, can be considered as the quotient set $(\mathbb{R} / \sim)$?

Comment: This is not answering your question. I just wanted to say, that this is nothing "special": Given a function $f : A \to B$, define $x\sim y \Leftrightarrow f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x,y\in A$. Then $\sim$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.

Comment: Yes, in the sense that there is a bijection $\Bbb R / \sim \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$. This is the descent of the absolute value map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R_{\geq 0}$, $x \mapsto |x|$, via the quotient map $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R / \sim$ defined by $\sim$.

Comment: Note that, due to $$ x^2 - y^2 = (x-y)(x+y) $$ we have $x/\mathord\sim = \{x,-x\}$. So I do not think that $\sim$ is interesting. But, yes, $\mathbf R/\mathord\sim \cong \mathbf R^+_0$.

Comment: It's a special case of kernel relation (the general case is exactly what @StefanPerko describes).

Comment: @martini, is $R_{\geq 0}$ *equal to* or is it *isomorphic to* $(\mathbb{R} / \sim)$?

Comment: isomorphic as what?

Comment: @Travis, thank you, this helped. Actually, the absolute value function was the reason why I thought about this equivalence relation.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found my it useful.

Comment: @MooS: Hm, good point. Neither $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ nor $(\mathbb{R} / \sim)$ are fields, not to mention subfields of $\mathbb{R}$, which is why they cannot be isomorphic as fields. But then, why are we justified to use the operations of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Every equivalence relation $\sim$ on some set $X$ can be identified with the canonical surjection $X\to X/\sim$. Yours corresponds to the surjection $\mathbb R\to [0,\infty)$, $x\mapsto|x|$, hence one could call it *the absolute value*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not much to say about this relation and thus it does not deserve a special name:

If $\mathbb F$ has characteristic $2$, it just the equality-relation, since $x^2=y^2 \Longleftrightarrow x=y$.

Otherwise we have $x^2=y^2 \Longleftrightarrow x=y \text{ or } x=-y$, hence the relation pairs any element of the field with its additive inverse.